# Add html markup in fabricjs container

Tags: canvas, html5-canvas, richtextbox, fabricjs

Considering canvas doesn't have support for rich text features e.g. bulleted list, tables etc. Is there a way to contain html markup in a fabricjs container, which will take care of the following:

1. Getting fabricjs handles for the div
2. Handles double click event
3. Div is bound to the canvas boundaries